# Centering Equation in Aligned Math Environment

Tags: math-mode

I am wondering how to center parts of equations in an aligned environment. I want it to look like this:
[image]
or this:
[image]
currently my my code is as shown below however it is not giving me the result that I would like:

```
$$\lvert x \rvert = \left\{ \begin{aligned}
    &x,\quad & \text{for $x \geqslant 0$} \\
    -&x,\quad & \text{for $x < 0$.}
    \end{aligned} \right. $$

$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{aligned}
    {\textstyle\frac{3}{2}}, &\text{for $ x > 0$} \\
    \text{undefined},\quad & \text{for $x=0$} \\
    {\textstyle\frac{2}{3}}, & \text{for $x < 0$}
    \end{aligned} \right.$$
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to define your own environment by modifying `cases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{casescentered}
 {\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}}
 {\endarray\right.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\lvert x \rvert = 
\begin{casescentered}
  x, & \text{for $x \geqslant 0$} \\
  -x,& \text{for $x < 0$.}
\end{casescentered}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
\begin{casescentered}
  \tfrac{3}{2},     & \text{for $ x > 0$} \\
  \text{undefined}, & \text{for $x=0$} \\
  \tfrac{2}{3},     & \text{for $x < 0$}
\end{casescentered}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\lvert x \rvert = 
\begin{cases}
  x, & \text{for $x \geqslant 0$} \\
  -x,& \text{for $x < 0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  \tfrac{3}{2},     & \text{for $ x > 0$} \\
  \text{undefined}, & \text{for $x=0$} \\
  \tfrac{2}{3},     & \text{for $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Please, don't use `$$` in LaTeX, for any reason.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `array` instead:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[\lvert x \rvert = \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l}
     x,   & \text{for $x \geqslant 0$} \\
    -x,   & \text{for $x < 0$.}
    \end{array} \right. \]

\[f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l}
    \tfrac{3}{2},     & \text{for $ x > 0$} \\
    \text{undefined}, & \text{for $x=0$} \\
    \tfrac{2}{3},     & \text{for $x < 0$}
    \end{array} \right. \]

\end{document}
```

> [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY8cr.png]